# Loading non-ascii characters with mysql infile

Tags: mysql, non-ascii-characters

I have a utf-8_general_ci column. When I insert a column via `"INSERT INTO mytable (column) value ('MÃLL')"` everything is fine and the row gets inserted.

I am trying to do bulk inserts with the infile command, but it fails on the non-ascii characters and cuts the name off...the value in the database ends up being 'M' rather than 'MÃLL'

The text file I am loading from has the correct value. Here is my statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE INTO table mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (column)
```

I get the following warning:
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xC3O ...' for column 'column' at row 1

How do I load this file correctly?

Comment: http://blog.datispars.com/loading-utf8-text-data-into-a-mysql-table/

Comment: thanks Rufo but that didn't seem to do it. I think you're on the right path with specifying the character set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957900/loading-utf-8-encoded-text-into-mysql-table this solved for me