# SQL - LOAD DATA INFILE - UTF8 issue

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

I get few big database exported to .txt (its around 5GB each) so i found out that i can easy import it with

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;

it works well but i am having problem with UTF-8 there, because some texts are displaying like PODBÂ¦H Z L DODATELNÂ¦ ZPRACOVAT even that column charset is set for UTF-8 and in .txt file its displayed OK, so problem is somewhere in import. Any idea how can i import it without  this problems?

Comment: Is the .txt file UTF8 encoded ?

Comment: Yea it is. + In .txt file it display right, so there is problem in import process in my opinion

Comment: Try running SET NAMES 'utf8' before your request

Comment: `SET character_set_database=utf8;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/db/something.txt' INTO TABLE something_table;`
Not working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this : [Loading utf-8 encoded text into MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957900/loading-utf-8-encoded-text-into-mysql-table)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/pet.txt' 
INTO TABLE pet
CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```