# Error Importing CSV to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to use this code to import a `csv` file into my MySQL database:

... **Thanks for solved that question!!** ....

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Guys I could solved that problem but now... I have an other problem, this is the code now:**

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = "cauctti"; 
$databasetable = "sample"; 
$databaseusername="root"; 
$databasepassword = "toor"; 
$fieldseparator = ";"; 
$lineseparator = "\r|n";
$csvfile = "Reporting.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
      LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

When I try to run it, only insert one row on the table...

> Loaded a total of 1 records from this csv file.

Why it only gets one row when my csv file have like 5.000 entries...

Comment: Got your answer there I think:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256421/sql-load-data-infile-utf8-issue

Comment: You should add CHARACTER SET UTF8; to your query.

Comment: Matheno Where exactly i need to add it?

Comment: @Matheno Is the first time I use PDO

Comment: Should be something like : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator))." CHARACTER SET UTF8";

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957900/loading-utf-8-encoded-text-into-mysql-table)

You should set **CHARACTER SET UTF8** in your query.

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file'
IGNORE INTO TABLE table
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here --> [Here](http://www.amitpatil.me/csv-to-mysql-importer-php-script/)

```
<?php
$table    = "tableName";
$fileName = "States.csv";
$ignoreFirstRow = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($fileName, "r")) !== FALSE){
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
if($ignoreFirstRow != 1){
$sql = "insert into ".$table." values(";
$sql .= '"'.implode('","',$data).'"';
echo "".$sql.');';
$sql = "";
}
$ignoreFirstRow++;
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```