# Load data infile default encoding

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

While trying to use the LOAD DATA INFILE command in MYSQL (InnoDB), I had trouble getting the encoding to work.

```
"something","something else",\N,"ANOTHER","2012-05-05T19:54:03","2012-12-08T16:14:53","SOMETHING","Something","Hello","HIHI","HEY","999.0","0.01","0.25","06/2012",\N,"2012-06-28","2012-06-28","2012-06-28","2009-03-02","2012-06-28",\N,"LOLOL","","LOLNON",\N,
```

Became

```
獯浥瑨楮朢Ⱒ獯浥瑨楮朠敬獥       䅎佔䡅刢Ⱒ㈰ㄲⴰ㔭〵吱㤺㔴㨰㌢Ⱒ㈰ㄲⴱ㈭〸吱㘺ㄴ㨵㌢Ⱒ协䵅呈䥎䜢Ⱒ卯浥瑨楮朢Ⱒ䡥汬漢Ⱒ䡉䡉   䡅夢Ⱒ㤹㤮〢Ⱒ〮〱   \N  \N  ㈰ㄲⴰ㘭㈸   ㈰〹ⴰ㌭〲   ㈰ㄲⴰ㘭㈸       䱏䱏䰢Ⱒ    0   0   \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N
```

Other people had similar problems, which were solved, as was mine, by setting the charset to 'utf8'. (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957900/loading-utf-8-encoded-text-into-mysql-table) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256421/sql-load-data-infile-utf8-issue)) In none of the questions or answers was it clear why utf8 wouldn't work automatically.

This seemed strange, since people often mentioned that they were using utf8 as a default encoding, and I was encoding the data in UTF-8 format in Notepad++ with a table default collation of "utf8 - default collation".

I looked further and saw that my schema default charset is `utf16` with a default collation of `utf16_general_ci`. I believe that MYSQL uses the ***schema*** default charset and collation for LOAD DATA INFILE commands.

Does MYSQL use the schema charset for defaults on `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and if so, where is that documented? If not, where does the default charset come from?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes.

> The server uses the character set indicated by the character_set_database system variable to interpret the information in the file. SET NAMES and the setting of character_set_client do not affect interpretation of input. If the contents of the input file use a character set that differs from the default, it is usually preferable to specify the character set of the file by using the CHARACTER SET clause. A character set of binary specifies “no conversion.”

and this is found right near the top of the [documentation for LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

If you set that variable dynamically, then you could claim that you're not using the *schema* default, but that would be stretching the point.