# Java jdbc records from console to database java.sql.sqlexception:

Tags: java, jdbc

Code for values that are taken from user and inserted into database but gives error

"java.sql.SQLException: The column position '45' is out of range. The number of columns for this ResultSet is '2'."

when user enters 45 as number, the code takes that as column number which is 2
what must be changed so that number is the literal that goes in the column id the table has two columns named ID and Name;

```java
package Rdbms;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Jdbcfrnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        String drv = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Oracle;create=true;";
        String user = "Android";
        String password = "java";

        Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        Connection dbConnection = null;

        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            // 0. read user input from command line: last name, first name and email
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
                        int a;
                        a = sc.nextInt();                                                                                   

            System.out.print("Enter your Name: ");
            String firstName = scanner.nextLine();

                        //System.out.print("Enter your email: ");
                        //String email = scanner.nextLine();

            // 1. Get a connection to database
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // 2. Create a statement
            String sql = "insert into GOOD "
                    + " (ID, Name)" + " values (?, ?)";

            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            // set param values
            myStmt.setString(a , firstName);
            //myStmt.setString(ID, "Android");

            // 3. Execute SQL query
            myStmt.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Insert complete.");
            } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            if (myStmt != null) {
                myStmt.close();
            }

            if (myConn != null) {
                myConn.close();
            }

            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when user enters 45 as number, the code takes that as column number which is 2

That does not make sense. Your code is making 45 the column number, as the error says

> The column position '45' is out of range.

Try making a separate variable for which column you're setting

```
myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
int col = 1;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
int a= sc.nextInt();
myStmt.setInt(col++, a);

System.out.print("Enter your Name: ");
String firstName = sc.nextLine();
myStmt.setString(col++ , firstName);
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to add records from csv file to database cause there are lot of records, thanks

Comment: @foursystems, yes it's possible. Write some code that would do it.

Comment: @foursystems I have no experience with loading data to a  Derby database. MySQL, Postgres, Mongo, etc all have import tools that are specific to them.

Answer (score 1):

> java.sql.SQLException: The column position '45' is out of range. The number of columns for this ResultSet is '2'

As you mentioned, *when user enters 45 as number, the code takes that as column number which is 2*. Now, same input you have specified as column position

```
int a;
a = sc.nextInt();
...
...
myStmt.setString(a , firstName);
```

Please note, first argument of [`setString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) is `parameterIndex`, which your misunderstood with value. Instead, you should have

```
myStmt.setInt(1, a);
myStmt.setString(2, firstName);
```

Comment: what do i have to change so that user could enter number and name that goes in the database

Comment: thanks works now, while you are still there is it possible to add records from csv file to database cause there are lot of records, thanks

Comment: @foursystems there are many ways you could achieve. I would suggest to research yourself on this topic, which suits your requirement. Write some code and comeback to us with your specific problem (if any). All the best:-)

Comment: @foursystems make sure you read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @foursystems did you accepted the answer ? you need to mark accepted as mentioned in that link. Let me know, if you have any confusion/queries on how to accept an answer

Comment: @foursystems https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730595/8686562 simplest approach

Comment: @foursystems https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/

Comment: @MahendraKapadne It is not recommended to share 3rd party links, they might get broken tomorrow and your comment/answer would be useless. If you have something different answer. Then, please go ahead and post it as an answer